# Facebook sharer show only my permalink and no further tags

Tags: facebook-sharer

I have an annoying problem with facebook sharer. Basically when I fire the popup passing all the required parameters, in the texbox which should contains the description, it appears only my permalink.
I woundering what's wrong as it's since ten days that I bang my head agains the desk. I can't go thru this. In the html of my page there are all the required og:tags, here's a snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
    <head id="Head1" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# thedynoroom: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/thedynoroom#"><meta charset="UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.famigliacristiana.it/liturgia/santetelberto-.aspx" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="[Il Santo del giorno] Sant’Etelberto " />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="it_IT" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://media.famigliacristiana.it/2014/1/24_885602.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Liturgia del giorno: Gc 3,13-18/ Sal 18/ Mc 9,14-29" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="video" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Famiglia Cristiana" />
    <meta property="og:updated_time" content="201401191038325888" />
<title>
    Sant’Etelberto - il Santo del giorno - 24 febbraio - Famiglia Cristiana
</title>
```

Dunno why facebook cannot read the tags, no one is catched from the sharer, only the permalink. Any hints?

Comment: I tried your url and facebook share button and it is working for me.